# Is there any better way to filter the output of git diff?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, git, diff

SO Question in Context : [Find out changed line numbers from git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61426894/10155936])

Based on the question above, I need to print the diff for modified files between two revisions in `git` in this format :

```
/path/to/file
startline1-startline2
startline3-startline4

/path/to/another/file
startline5-startline6
...
```

This is my [attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61429395/10155936) to filter `git` diff's output.

```
git diff --unified=0 --diff-filter=M HEAD~1 HEAD | \
grep -v -e '^[+-]' -e '^index' | \
sed 's/diff --git a.* b\//\//g; s/.*@@\(.*\)@@.*/\1/g; s/^ -//g; s/,[0-9]*//g; s/\(^[0-9]*\) +/\1-/g;'
```

I am not sure if the above command satisfies all cases which `git diff` might show in the output.

Can the existing solution be improved or is there any better way to do this using some other utility like `awk` or in `git` itself?

---

Based on the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582649/408757) given by [@muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru), here's a comparison :

```
# Using git diff [expected output w.r.t line numbers and not formatting]

$ git diff --unified=0 --diff-filter=M HEAD~3 HEAD | grep -v -e '^[+-]' -e '^index'
diff --git a/lib/get-config.js b/lib/get-config.js
@@ -89,0 +90,5 @@ module.exports = {
diff --git a/lib/pull.js b/lib/pull.js
@@ -62 +62 @@ module.exports = class Pull {
@@ -83 +83 @@ module.exports = class Pull {
diff --git a/lib/router.js b/lib/router.js
@@ -3,0 +4 @@ const yaml = require('js-yaml')
@@ -125,0 +127 @@ module.exports = app => {
@@ -136,0 +139 @@ module.exports = app => {
```

```
# Using external diff as suggested by @muru
# [expected output with formatting but line numbers don't match with git diff's output]

$ git -c diff.external='./foo.sh' diff --diff-filter=M 'HEAD~3' HEAD
/tmp/AAAA_get-config.js
90-89

/tmp/BBBB_pull.js
62
83

/tmp/CCCC_router.js
4-3
126-125
137-136
```

The line numbers are different for the file `router.js`.

[Repository](https://github.com/wei/pull) used for comparison.

---

I would like to clarify what format is being expected in the output.

`git diff` generates output in unified diff format. The format is something like this :

```
# Assumes --unified=0 i.e no context lines
diff --git a/path/to/file b/path/to/file
index x..z mode
--- a/path/to/file
+++ b/path/to/file
@@ -l1,s +l2,s @@ optional section heading
- ...
- ...
+ ...
+ ...
diff --git a/path/to/file1 b/path/to/file1
index y..z mode
--- a/path/to/file1
+++ b/path/to/file2
@@ -l3,s +l4,s @@ optional section heading
- ...
- ...
+ ...
+ ...
.
.
.
```

The expected output should contain diff for only modified files (using `--diff-filer=M`) and should be in this format :

```
/path/to/file
l1-l2

/path/to/file1
l3-l4
l5-l6
.
.
.
```

Here `l1`,`l2`... are line numbers as mentioned in the unified diff format (`@@ -l1,s +l2,s @@`).

---

[@muru's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582649/408757) almost solves the problem but the line numbers obtained using this changed group format `'%df%(f=l?:-%dl)\n'` don't match the line numbers in unified diff format.

Is there a way to represent the line numbers(in unified diff format) using options such as `changed-group-format` ?

---

Here's a MVCE using [bash git repository](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash)

Using `git diff`,

```
$ git diff --unified=0 --diff-filter=M 9e49d ad1b3 | grep -v -e '^[+-]' -e '^index'
diff --git a/execute_cmd.c b/execute_cmd.c
@@ -567 +567 @@ execute_command_internal (command, asynchronous, pipe_in, pipe_out,
@@ -753,2 +753 @@ execute_command_internal (command, asynchronous, pipe_in, pipe_out,
@@ -759,2 +758 @@ execute_command_internal (command, asynchronous, pipe_in, pipe_out,
@@ -1104 +1102 @@ execute_command_internal (command, asynchronous, pipe_in, pipe_out,
diff --git a/patchlevel.h b/patchlevel.h
@@ -28 +28 @@
diff --git a/subst.c b/subst.c
@@ -5339 +5339 @@ clear_fifo_list ()
@@ -5345 +5345 @@ copy_fifo_list (sizep)
@@ -5411,7 +5411,2 @@ unlink_fifo_list ()
@@ -5433 +5428 @@ close_new_fifos (list, lsize)
@@ -5437 +5431,0 @@ close_new_fifos (list, lsize)
@@ -5445,2 +5439,2 @@ close_new_fifos (list, lsize)
@@ -5568 +5562 @@ clear_fifo_list ()
@@ -5572 +5566 @@ copy_fifo_list (sizep)
@@ -5578 +5572 @@ copy_fifo_list (sizep)
@@ -5583 +5577 @@ copy_fifo_list (sizep)
@@ -5656 +5650 @@ close_new_fifos (list, lsize)
@@ -5660 +5653,0 @@ close_new_fifos (list, lsize)
@@ -5668,2 +5661,2 @@ close_new_fifos (list, lsize)
diff --git a/subst.h b/subst.h
@@ -276,2 +276,3 @@ extern void unlink_fifo __P((int));
```

Expected output

```
/execute_cmd.c
567-567 
753-753 
759-758 
1104-1102 

/patchlevel.h
28-28 

/subst.c
5339-5339 
5345-5345 
5411-5411 
5433-5428 
5437-5431 
5445-5439 
5568-5562 
5572-5566 
5578-5572 
5583-5577 
5656-5650 
5660-5653 
5668-5661 

/subst.h
276-276
```

Output Based on [@muru's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582649/408757)

```
# Line numbers which don't match the expected output is indicated by "#"
$ git -c diff.external='../foo.sh' diff --diff-filter=M 9e49d ad1b3
/tmp/2wJaWf_execute_cmd.c
567
753-754 #
759-760 #
1104 #

/tmp/7j19Ob_patchlevel.h
28

/tmp/fQDY8b_subst.c
5339
5345
5411-5417 #
5433 #
5437 #
5445-5446 #
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you put the relevant context in *this* question? Include example input and what output you is desired, and what you're having problems with.

Comment: @muru I have updated the details

Comment: @EdMorton Any idea how we can represent the unified diff format using options such as `changed-group-format` so that this `@@ -l1,s +l2,s @@` can be represented as this `l1-l2`?

Answer (score 4):

You can get something similar if you use GNU diff, and make `git diff` call it:

`foo.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/255212/2072269 for details on parameters
echo "$2" # print filename
diff --changed-group-format $'%df%(f=l?:-%dl)\n' --line-format='' "$2" "$5"
echo
exit 0
```

And (example using [the bash git repo](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash)):

```
$ export GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF="$PWD/foo.sh"
$ git diff HEAD 'HEAD^^'
execute_cmd.c
567
753-754
759-760
1104

patchlevel.h
28

subst.c
5339
5345
5411-5417
5433
5437
5445-5446
5568
5572
5578
5583
5656
5660
5668-5669

subst.h
276-277
```

The [GNU `diff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Line-Group-Formats.html#Line-Group-Formats) options:

> `--changed-group-format=`*format*
>       These line groups are hunks containing lines from both files.

`%df` and `%dl` are the `f`irst and `l`ast line numbers of the change group in the old file (in `d`ecimal). `%(f=l?:-%dl)` is a ternary expression comparing `f` and `l` and omitting the last line if its the same as the first.

We don't need the actual lines, so `--line-format` is set to empty.

---

Based on the MCVE, it seems:

1. You don't need the `%(f=l?:-%dl)` ternary check (which omits the second number if its the same as the first). We just need to print the second number.
2. The second number should be `%F` for most cases - the first line of the change from the new file. Except where lines are just deleted from the old file, so the number of lines in the new file are 0. In that case, the number printed is `%E` - the line number just before the group in the new file. The ternary then becomes `%(N=0?%dE:%dF)`.
3. I should use `$1` for the filename instead of `$2`.

So, with those changes:

```
#! /bin/bash
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/255212/2072269 for details on parameters
echo "$1" # print filename
diff --changed-group-format $'%df-%(N=0?%dE:%dF)\n' --line-format='' "$2" "$5"
echo
exit 0
```

which gives the expected output:

```
$ PAGER=cat git diff --unified=0 --diff-filter=M 9e49d ad1b3
execute_cmd.c
567-567
753-753
759-758
1104-1102

patchlevel.h
28-28

subst.c
5339-5339
5345-5345
5411-5411
5433-5428
5437-5431
5445-5439
5568-5562
5572-5566
5578-5572
5583-5577
5656-5650
5660-5653
5668-5661

subst.h
276-276
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the line numbers sometimes differ from the git diff's output, I am guessing its got something to do with various options of `'Fn'` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Line-Group-Formats.html#Line-Group-Formats) as some options under it mentions `e+1` , `l-f+1`, what line number format `git diff` might be using ? (if its using the default, then what is the default format?)

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari It's probably the same as GNU diff's unified format (https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified)

Comment: The difference of line numbers between the `git diff` and `git diff` with external `diff` as `foo.sh` : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jeQH.png ,

Is the unified format being used in `foo.sh` ?

Comment: Any idea why the line numbers are different ?

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari maybe because your example is mostly of deleted lines. Please don't post screenshots of text. If you have new information to add, edit it into your question *as text*.

Comment: I have updated the question with the details

Comment: I think the reason for line numbers being different is because I am using unified diff format (`--unified=0`) in git diff. Is it possible to represent the unified diff  using options such as `changed-group-format`? That is instead of displaying this `@@ -89,0 +90,5 @@` display only `89-90`

Comment: I have added a MVCE

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari the MCVE helps. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update, it does work with MVCE. However it doesnot work with the previous example shown in the comparison section. I have created a repl [here](https://repl.it/repls/ForestgreenImmaterialInstitutions), you can check the same without cloning the repository.

Comment: Any thoughts on this ? I only have an hour left to assign the bounty

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari it seems  you just need the same check in (2) for the first number as well - a format of `$'%(n=0?%de:%df)-%(N=0?%dE:%dF)\n'` seems to work with your repl.

Comment: This works for the repository in the repl link, however fails for the MVCE